# What alien species was Riza?

Tags: men-in-black, men-in-black-international

Riza looked human.

[image: Riza, the Merchant of Death]

But, she had 4 arms. What alien species she belonged to?

Comment: She could be a Shokan?

Comment: I just got it. She's an arms dealer. Arms. Dealer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MiB: International novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/43778563-men-in-black-international) (or rather the short story *Open Arms* found at the end of said novel), she's a ***'Tribrachian'***. As is so often the case in the film series, her species name appears to be a fair [description of her primary trait](https://meninblack.fandom.com/wiki/Ballchinian), her three arms.

> H pulled back for a second and looked at Riza. “*You… you’ve got three arms!*”
>   Riza smiled. “*Brimming with biceps and brains, just the way I like them.*”
>   **“*You’re a Tribrachian!*”**
>
> <sub><sup>[Men in Black International: The Official Movie Novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/43778563-men-in-black-international)</sup></sub>